# js external link ($ was used befor it was defined )

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an external js file to link my HTML. and i did it like this between head tags but i have many problems

```
<script src="D:/web/test.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

my js code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).animated({height:+=10px});
    });
    $(".product").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).animated({height:-=10px});
    });
});
```

[image: the errors]

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` library?

Answer (score 0):

Head section should be

```
<script type="javascript/text" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="D:/web/test.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

This will be the order of `JavaScript` files in head section.

First load the `jQuery` then use it.

**Updated answer**

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
```

Add this lines on top of your `jQuery` code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Here you go with the solution `/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/`